# Find a, b, c that have property x[a][b] = x[a][c] = x[b][c]

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search

I have two-dimensional array named `x`. I want to count all three-element groups in which `x[a][b] = x[a][c] = x[b][c]`, as fast as possible, of course. I don't need to know those elements, I only need quantity of those groups.

Size of the first dimension of that array equals size of the second.

I know the brute-force solution, it has a complexity of O(n^2), where n is size of an array. I suppose there is a quicker solution, but I have no idea what does it look like.

Comment: Belongs on the CS site.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any way apart from brute force.

Search each row for a pair, then check the x[b][c] for that pair.

Let the array be `NxN`. Comparing each element of a row with each other element of the row takes

```
N choose 2 = N(N-1)/2 = O(N^2)
```

comparisons and you need to do it for all `N` rows giving `O(N^3)`. If your talking total size (`M=N^2`) then its `O(N^(3/2))`.

Comment: I think you missed the "as fast as possible" part of the question.

Comment: @Thomas You are welcome to provide a proof or some intuition that this should be possible faster than O(n^3).

Comment: @us2012 I believe the job of proving your solution is optimal falls on you, my friend :)

Comment: @Thomas If you compare the user names, you'll see that it's not mine. I'm merely saying that your comment is unnecessarily snarky given that you don't provide any reason why this shouldn't be as fast as possible.

Comment: @us2012 Oops.. sorry about that, haha. And I wasn't trying to be snarky, just that the OP already said he is aware of the brute force solution, and was looking for a faster one.

Comment: I would be amazed to see something faster than this. Maybe there is a trick using linear algebra and matrices though?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the brute force solution would be O(N^3)

A different solution (other than the trivial (0,0,0)) would be to put each pair in a hash table using its value as the key.  Then look for pairs that match your criterion within the duplicates.